# Using page variables in Hugo

Tags: go, hugo

I am using Hugo after moving from Jekyll. Something is confusing me about page variables though. If I use `.IsHome` inside the header and footer partials, it works. But it fails for any partial template inside the content area. I have no idea why this happens, despite reading multiple docs about the 'dot'.

Answer (score 0):

In Hugo, `.` gives you the current context. In a page, this has `.IsHome`. But it doesn't cascade down to partials unless you explicitly pass it. You're probably including your header and footer partials like so:

```
{{- partial "header.html" . -}}
```

The `.` in there passes along the current context to the header partial. Note that there's nothing special about header or footer partials in Hugo: they don't get any special treatment when it comes to the context. I'm guessing that you are including the other partials like so:

```
{{- partial "otherpartial.html" -}}
```

Notice that there isn't any `.` in there to pass along the context. In Hugo, context is never implictly given to partials: you have to explicitly pass it. The solution is to make sure you're passing the context to your partials (notice the added `.`):

```
{{- partial "otherpartial.html" . -}}
```

Comment: I would only add that you would need to match Smitop's answer with the context of the variable. I.e. In a partial, let's call it "pagination.html" .IsHome is being run on pagination.html - but pagination.html doesn't have an .IsHome value, it's a partial, it has it's own context (just like a function or class). 
Your page however, does have an IsHome value. So when you pass you partial the context of the page (passing the partial the "." when the partial is called from your page . in that case = page context) . Then .IsHome is run on the context of the page.

Comment: @Smitop I am actually calling all partials (including the header and footer partials) like so `{{ partial "name.html" . }}` which is confusing because it works for the footer and header! But in the other cases, it doesn't. @Rogelio That part about passing the context is the one that is confusing me a lot.

Comment: You'd have to show me the code for me to spot the specific problem, but to maybe give more understanding. Context is "The data reachable by a certain point of the code" We don't want all data available to all points. Imagine if for a cook book you had to read every recipe to crack an egg? So each different part and piece has it's own data available to it. "Context". .IsHome is only applicable to the context of the page. If the partial doesn't have or hasn't been given the Page Context .IsHome can't run (A partial has it's own context). It's really hammering out the definition of "context".

Comment: Let me give an example. I want this inside section-title.html partial 
`{{if .IsHome }}
{{.CurrentSection.Title}}
{{ else }}
<a href="{{.CurrentSection.Title}}">{{.CurrentSection.Title}}</a>
{{ end }}`
then call it in a template as `{{ partial "section-title.html"}}`

Comment: .IsHome isn't applicable to your partial. You aren't telling it, conceptually  "if .Page.IsHome". So you need to make sure your code - whether passing the context "." or by another method of referencing .Page, checks if THAT page .isHome. The partial ISN'T home and will never be. It's not a page, it can't be. so when you check {{ if "this partial" .IsHome}} it won't work. The Partial doesn't have an ishome property.